# Как в отсортированном по двум полям наборе для каждого значения первого поля получить N по счету строку?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `payments` со следующей структурой:

```
user_id - идентификатор пользователя
order_id - идентификатор платежа
pay_dt - дата-время платежа
```

Как составить запрос, который будет возвращать третью, например, по счету строчку, в отсортировке по pay_dt для каждого пользователя?

Первый можно получить используя TOP(1) + ORDER BY. А третий?
СУБД My SQL

Comment: Укажите СУБД. И более подробно опишите проблему.

Comment: @Denis, не по теме немного. Подготовил ответ(на случай, если вопрос будет переформулирован надлежащим образом), но удалил его. Он как удалённый пользователю виден?

Comment: @pegoopik нет не виден, много репы надо что бы видеть удаленные вопросы/ответы

Comment: @pegoopik да, я видел ответ, вроде правильный был навскидку) нет, не должен быть виден.

Comment: @pegoopik Первый день пользуюсь сервисом, подскажи, что не так в формулировке вопроса? Удаленный ответ не виден.

Comment: "Помогите составить" или "составьте за меня"? Первое предполагает, что вы уже попробовали и столкнулись с какой-то проблемой. Изложите свои соображения о том, как такая задача, по-вашему, должна решаться.

Comment: @pegoopik попытался спасти вопрос, может опубликуете свой ответ

Comment: @Александр, вопрос должен быть сформулирован в более общем виде. Т.е. так, чтобы был полезен кому-то ещё. Ваш выглядит как "сделайте задание за меня". А должен выглядеть как "как решать подобные задачи, я пробовал так, у меня не получается" - и пример кода с ошибкой. Это если кратко.

Comment: @pegoopik может сможете предложить как сформулировать заголовок что бы попасть на него через поиск? я что то не придумаю

Comment: @Bald, "Как в отсортированном наборе получить строку с конкретным номером?" - отправил соотв. правку.

Comment: В предыдущем исправлении упустил соль вопроса:( Сформулировал как сумел. Помогите подобрать более краткую формулировку вопроса. Возможно: аналог PARTITION BY в MySQL.

Comment: @Александр, привыкайте. К сожалению тут теперь много народа, который увидев вопрос, решения которого не знает, начинает ругать вопрос (в общем, пенять на зеркало...)

Comment: @Александр По первоначальной постановке вопроса, исходя из того, что дата при переводе в строку 10 символов и не будет NULL значений то `select user_id,substr(group_concat(pay_dt order by pay_dt), 11*3, 10) from table group by user_id`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL Server; Oracle; PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT user_id, pay_dt, order_id
FROM(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY pay_dt, order_id)N, P.*
  FROM payments P
)T
WHERE N=3
```

**UPD:** удалил ошибочные ответы. не учёл, что нужно для каждого пользователя...

**UPD2:** без самоджойнов для MySQL приходит в голову только такое решение:

```
SELECT user_id, pay_dt, order_id
FROM(
  SELECT payments.*,
    @I := IF(user_id = @UserId, @I:=@I+1, @I:=1) N,
    @UserId := user_id user_id
  FROM payments, (SELECT @I := 0, @UserId := null)I
  ORDER BY user_id, pay_dt, order_id
)T
WHERE N=3
```

Как это работает: сортируем в порядке `user_id`, `pay_dt`, смотрим, если текущий `user_id` равен предыдущему, тогда прибавляем к `@I` единицу, иначе присваиваем ей `1`(начинаем заново нумеровать для нового пользователя).
Аналог `PARTITION BY` в `ROW_NUMBER` других СУБД при нумерации.

**По совету mike:**

```
SELECT user_id,  SUBSTR(GROUP_CONCAT(pay_dt ORDER BY pay_dt), 41, 19)pay_dt_3rd
FROM payments
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*)>=3
```

Comment: в `mysql` помоему нет `top`, там вроде `limit`

Comment: @Bald, точно, поправил, спасибо.

Comment: @pegoopik Кстати, при первоначальной постановке вопроса "получить дату" (т.е. одно поле) можно было спокойно решать через `substr(group_concat(date order by ...))`. И кстати `IF(user_id=@UserId,@I+1,1)` удобнее этого громадного case

Comment: @Mike, If добавлю, раз уж речь исключительно о MySQL. а так желательно писать в ANSII. По поводу substr - изначально вопрос заминусовали -> с моей стороны были попытки его вытащить, сформулировал в более общем виде. Не очень удачно. Напиши свой ответ с комментарием, лишним не будет, автору так уж точно.

Comment: @pegoopik case конечно ansi, только вот в оракле его аж до 9й версии  не было, так что совместимость в SQL это такое натянутое понятие :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Good_Ids.user_id as user_id , 

(SELECT pay_dt FROM payments 
WHERE payments.user_id = Good_Ids.user_id 
ORDER BY pay_dt 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2) AS Third_Order 

FROM (SELECT user_id 
FROM payments 
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3) AS Good_Ids;
```

Немного разобрался в теме, думаю, этот код тоже подойдет. В него так же включил проверку того, что для данного юзера существует третий платеж. Что скажете?

Comment: у вас два чтения из payments. Я в ответ добавил пример от Mike, посмотрите.